# Why getDefaultDisplay().getSize(Point size) is updating its argument instead of returning a value?

Tags: android, thread-synchronization

Its actual implementation is,

```
public void getSize(Point outSize) {
    synchronized (this) {
        updateDisplayInfoLocked();
        mDisplayInfo.getAppMetrics(mTempMetrics, mDisplayAdjustments);
        outSize.x = mTempMetrics.widthPixels;
        outSize.y = mTempMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
}
```

and also the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)) didn't mention this particular design.

Could this be because of synchronization? How effective would this be if it is returned instead? Just curious.

Also, why `Point` is used instead of `Dimensions` as `Dimensions` seems to be meaningful in this context. 
My apologies and please ignore if this question is too dumb.

Comment: Probably because the guy who developed this part though it would be better

Comment: "Could this be because of synchronization?" -- probably not. Usually, this pattern is to encourage object reuse, to avoid creating objects unnecessarily. This is particularly important when rendering the UI, where you want to avoid object allocation during `onDraw()` processing. Here, the caller can perhaps use a previously-allocated `Point` rather than `getSize()` always instantiating a new one.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare. thats useful.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that this design is used to encourage object-reuse just as in comments